# Верстка , позиционирование

Tags: html, css

Имеется такая таблица, нужно чтобы когда экран был меньше width-ом , то он переместился после инпутов слева. Как реализовать, не пойму. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?php  include "db.php" ?>
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="card mb-3">
            <div class="card-header">Ավելացնել Ապրանք</div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <form action="/admin/add" method="post">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Անուն</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Տեսակ</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="description">
                            </div>
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Մոդել</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="model">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Տարի</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="tari">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Շարժիչ</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="sharjich">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Վազք</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="vazq">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Գինը</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="price">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Բռանդի Իդին</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="brand_id">
                            </div>
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Կատեգորիա Իդին</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="categorie_id">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Տեքստ</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="text"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Изображение</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="file" name="img">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Ավելացնել</button>
                        </form>

                        </div>
                        <div class="categorikner" style="float: right;position: fixed;left: 60%; ">
                       <table border="1px" style="text-align: center;">
                       <tr>
                           <th>id</th>
                           <th>Կատեգորիաի Անունը</th>
                       </tr>
                            <?php $categories = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT id, title FROM `tovari_categories`") ?>
<?php while ($cat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($categories)) {

                     echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>" . $cat['id'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $cat['title'] . "</td>";
                     echo "</tr>";

                         } ?>
                        </table>
                        <br><br>
                        <table border="1px" style="text-align: center;">
                       <tr>
                           <th>id</th>
                           <th>Բռենդի  Անունը</th>
                           <th>Կատեգորիան Բռենդի</th>
                       </tr>
                            <?php $categories = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT id, title, categorie_id FROM `brand_id`") ?>
<?php while ($cat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($categories)) {

                     echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>" . $cat['id'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $cat['title'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $cat['categorie_id'] . "</td>";
                     echo "</tr>";

                         } ?>
                        </table>
                     </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: На картинке то что должно быть? Или то что сейчас? И можно код верстки

Comment: То что сейчас, хочу чтобы эти таблицы, на телефоне отображались после инпутов слева.

Comment: при самой простой верстке инлайнами/флексами при маленькой ширине, таблицы сами будут прыгать под инпуты

Comment: У меня скорее всего что-то не так, через минутку обновится пост, и будет код верстки.

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в том что нужно его в правильном диве поставить, не подскажите где лучше?

Comment: Или может быть дело в том, что у него фиксированная позиция. Скорее всего в этом, но мне нужно чтобы при маленькой ширине окна он лезал под ними, а при нормальном лежал с своим фикс позицией.

Comment: Вопрос решил тем, что изменил фиксацию на релайтив. Спасибо